# Count number of words in each attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

How would I go about this from that perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches one might take. Following your start to its logical conclusion, you've already ordered your items by `$count`, so you can bind these ordered items to a variable and retrieve the greatest one using the `fn:last()` function. You didn't provide source data, so here's a complete example demonstrating the approach:

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $people := 
    <people>
        <person age="42" name="molly"/>
        <person age="70" name="lucy"/>
        <person age="9" name="billy"/>
    </people>
let $ordered := 
    (
        for $person in $people/person
        order by $person/@age cast as xs:integer
        return
            $person
    )
let $oldest := $ordered[last()]
return
    $oldest
```

This will return the Lucy entry. (If we hadn't cast the values as `xs:integer` we would've gotten Billy.)

However, it's possible there will be two or more people who have the same greatest age. To return all entries with the maximum age, you could first find the maximum value, then select the items with that value:

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $people := 
    <people>
        <person age="42" name="molly"/>
        <person age="70" name="lucy"/>
        <person age="9" name="billy"/>
        <person age="70" name="holly"/>
    </people>
let $ages := $people/person/@age
let $max := max($ages)
let $oldest := $people/person[@age = $max]
return
    $oldest
```

This will return the Lucy and Holly entries. (We didn't have to cast the values as integer in this case because the `fn:max()` function casts all values of type `xs:anyAtomicType` as `xs:double`; see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-max.)

Or, in a more compact form:

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $people := 
    <people>
        <person age="42" name="molly"/>
        <person age="70" name="lucy"/>
        <person age="9" name="billy"/>
        <person age="70" name="holly"/>
    </people>
return
    $people/person[@age = max($people/person/@age)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your code, I think `max` with `for` should work using XPath 2.0+

```
max(for $country in doc("world.xml")/world/country
    return count(tokenize($country/@cities, '\s+')))
```

and then select the corresponding nodes

```
/world/country[count(tokenize(@cities, '\s+')) = max(for $country in /world/country
    return count(tokenize($country/@cities, '\s+')))]
```